# Example of an outer automorphism of a multiplicative group?

Tags: group-theory

Does such a thing exist?

By multiplicative group, I just mean that the group operation is multiplication. It could be any such group, commutative or not.

Comment: ok, So you want to _call_ the operation by the name "multiplication", but that doesn't say anything about the nature of the operation that wasn't already said when you said it was a group operation. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @michael-hardy Yeah, I was thinking of keeping the group and group operation abstract but I guess it's easier (necessary) to specialize. Can you think of any example using the group $\mathbb{Z}/\{0\}$ and multiplication as the operation?

Comment: $\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ isn't a group under multiplication....

Comment: @DaBamti, that's MichaelHardy's point. There is no "specialization" when you say multiplicative. We sometimes say a "multiplicative group" in the context of a set for which there is already a usual meaning of multiplication. In general, "multiplicative group" doesn't really mean anything. When you say multiplicative group, are you thinking of $(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)^*$, the group of units of $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 4):

Such examples are easy to find if you note that *every* nontrivial automorphism of an abelian group must be an outer automorphism. So for example, for any positive integer $m$ and any integer $a\not\equiv1\pmod m$ with $\gcd(a,m)=1$, the map $f\colon \Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ defined by $f(x) = ax$ is an outer automorphism of $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$. For another example, any nontrivial permutation of the three non-identity elements of the Klein $4$-group is an outer automorphism.

Comment: At first I was confused because f(x) = ax does not seem to preserve the identity. Then I relaized $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is only a group under addition, not multiplication. 1 is mapped to a, but 0 _is_ mapped to 0.